# How to prevent $state from refreshing any Component that does not rely on the $state.var being changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

We're using **[Angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)** for our app state management.

A problem we're having is that every component refreshes when the `$state` changes, even if it's a variable that is updated that does not exist/not used in some components.

For example, we have a TickersPanel and a TagsPanel. When a Ticker is selected, the TagsPanel should be updated and refreshed, however when a tag is selected in the TagsPanel, the TickersPanel should NOT refresh, but it currently does.

I found out that `{ notify: false }` is another object that can be passed in. However once I do that, NO components will refresh.

```
const save = (tag, terms) => {
    CONTAINER.push(tag);
    $state.go('charting', Term.write(terms), { notify: false }).then((stateResult) => {
        console.log('stateResult', stateResult);
    });
};
```

#### Has anyone found a way around this problem?

---

#### TagsPanel $onInit (Runs on every $state change)

```
this.$onInit = () => {
    tagsCol.addEventListener('scroll', scrollingTags);

    this.tags = [];
    this.limit = 30;

    const panelOpen = Dashboard.panelStatus(this.tagsOpen, this.chartMax);
    panelOpen ? buildTagList() : collapsePanel();
};
```

#### TickersPanel $onInit (Runs on every $state change, if `$state.params.ticker` did not change, then this should not be ran)

```
this.$onInit = () => {
    this.tickers = [];

    this.spy = {
        longname: "SPDR S&P 500",
        ticker: "SPY",
    };

    this.showTickersPanel = Dashboard.panelStatus(this.tagsOpen, this.chartMax);
    // const currentState = $state.params;
    // const prevState = Dashboard.getPreviousState();
    loadTickers().then(() => this.loadingTickersDone = true);
};
```

Comment: if i understand correctly then you might find usefull using ui-router-extras https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router-extras. You might want to look for the sticky states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've [made a JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwj9bdkL/3/) to describe a way to achieve what I've understood from your question using the uiRouter.

The fiddle uses [state inheritance](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-&-nested-views) and [named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-views) to only reinitialize the `tags` state when the `tickers` param changes.

```
[..]
// Using @ on the view names to refer to the absolute uiViews.
$stateProvider.state('tickers', {
    url: "",
    views: {
      'tickersPanel@': {
        template: [..]
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: "$ctrl",
        controller: function() {
          this.$onInit = function() {
            console.info('Tickers Panel $onInit');
            this.tickers = ["Ticker1", "Ticker2", "Ticker3"]
          }
        }
      },
      [..]
    }
});
$stateProvider.state('tags', {
    parent: 'tickers',
    url: "/:ticker",
    views: {
      'tagsPanel@': {
        template: [..]
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        bindToController: true,
        controller: function($stateParams) {
          this.$onInit = function() {
            console.info('Tags Panel 2 $onInit');
            this.ticker = $stateParams["ticker"];
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
[..]
```

Comment: Thanks! So the `ui-sref="tags` part would still translate into something like `$state.go('tags'` ?

Comment: Hey @LeonGaban, yeah, you can use it with the `$state` service too.

Comment: Ok, another 20 hours!

Comment: Hey so I made another plnkr with a much more similar app setup that I'm trying to solve. Running into that same problem here, mind a look? Will post another question soon: https://plnkr.co/edit/zfmuZXp88cSbdOsibv3y?p=preview

Comment: here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353725/how-to-prevent-sibling-state-controller-from-refreshing

Comment: Hey, I'm on holidays I'll check it out in a few weeks. Sorry.

Comment: Heya Leonardo, your code works for me in plnkr and jsfiddle, however in my real app running into a problem where I can't use `abstract:true` because I have to navigate from a `login` state to the `dashboard` state. Are you back from holidays and would like more points? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813677/how-to-get-child-state-template-controller-to-init-without-the-parent-state

Answer (score 0):

Why not just maintain the state in your component and return at the beginning of the function if the state hasn't changed?