# How to prevent sibling state controller from refreshing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

https://plnkr.co/edit/zfmuZXp88cSbdOsibv3y?p=preview

I have a main `dashboard` parent state with 2 child states `tags` and `tickers`.

When I click on a button in `tickers`, only the `tags` state should refresh. Currently they both refresh.

[image]

[image]

^ The `onInit tickersController` console.log should only be run once. However the tagsController should be run every time a ticker is clicked.

---

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dash');

    var dash = {
      name: 'dash',
      url: '/dash?ticker',
      params: {
        ticker: 'AAA'
      },
      views: {
        '': { templateUrl: 'dashboard.html' },
        'tagsList@dash': {
          url: '/tags',
          templateUrl: 'tags-list.html',
          controller: 'tagsController'
        },
        'tickersList@dash': {
          url: '/tickers',
          templateUrl: 'tickers-list.html',
          controller: 'tickersController'
        },
        'alertsList@dash': {
          url: '/alerts',
          templateUrl: 'alerts-list.html',
          controller: 'alertsController'
        }
      }
    };

    $stateProvider
      .state(dash);            
});

routerApp.controller('tagsController', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.ticker = $state.params.ticker;

    function getList(ticker) {
      switch(ticker) {
          case 'AAA' : return ['aaa tag 1', 'aaa tag 2', 'aaa tag 3'];
          case 'BBB' : return ['bbb tag 1', 'bbb tag 2', 'bbb tag 3'];
          case 'CCC' : return ['ccc tag 1', 'ccc tag 2', 'ccc tag 3'];
      } 
    }

    $scope.tags = getList($state.params.ticker);

    this.$onInit = function() {
      console.log('onInit tagsController');
    };
});

routerApp.controller('tickersController', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.changeScotchState = function(theTicker) {
        $state.go('dash', { ticker: theTicker });
    };

    $scope.tickers = [
      'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'
    ];

    this.$onInit = function() {
      console.log('onInit tickersController', $state.params.ticker);
    };
});

routerApp.controller('alertsController', function($scope, $state) {

    this.$onInit = function() {
      console.log('onInit alertsController', $state.params.ticker);
    };

});
```

Comment: could be by state change? so will be affected to tickets view?

Comment: Yeah, how would you avoid changing the tickers view as well? Or any other children. Basically I only want children of the dashboard to be refreshed if a particular state var that they need is changed. Actually I'm going to go ahead and add a 3rd controller.

Comment: updating url: '/tags', not parent view ?

Comment: The `ticker` param is declared on `dash`.  Whenever the `ticker` param changes, the `dash` state and all children are reloaded.  Move the `ticker` param to the child state, if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/iramGsSrJ2vKYvDPWFTb?p=preview

You can't keep a view from refreshing without moving it to the one of the parent states. Here's the changed states that should work

```js
    var tags = {
      name: 'dash.tags',
      url: '?ticker',
      views: {
        'tagsList@dash': {
          templateUrl: 'tags-list.html',
          controller: 'tagsController'
        }
      }
    }

var dash = {
  name: 'dash',
  url: '/dash',
  abstract: true,
  views: {
    '': { templateUrl: 'dashboard.html' },
    'tickersList@dash': {
      templateUrl: 'tickers-list.html',
      controller: 'tickersController'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but hmm in your example the tags-list isn't being displayed. I actually forked a new plnkr here with each state object broken out: https://plnkr.co/edit/NbB98J7TwUz5SrgE5jQn?p=preview

Comment: Updated the plunk. I forgot to add `abstract: true` on the parent state.

Comment: Heya so I tried to remove the ui-sref, so I can use `$state.go` inside of the Javascript and I'm getting an error `Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'dash'`, mind a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42371668/cannot-transition-to-abstract-state-angular-ui-router

Comment: The definition of an abstract state is that you can't switch to it. You must switch to the corresponding child state - `state.go('dash.tags', {ticker: 'something'})`

Answer (score 1):

i edited Your plunker to work without state refresh:

https://plnkr.co/edit/ntGVGQ06yVQC4W0Fl7A8?p=preview

The broadcast:

```
    $scope.changeScotchState = function(theTicker) {
   $rootScope.$broadcast('newData',  theTicker);
};
```

and $on:

```
   $scope.$on('newData', function(event, ticker){

      $scope.tags = getList(ticker);
      $scope.ticker = ticker;
    })
```

are the most important part and change.

Comment: Thanks! Your code also works as Stepans... curious though, I don't see where you used those events above?

Comment: in `tickersController` and `tagsController`. First i updated `changeScotchState` function and then get action in tagsCtrl

Comment: Both code works because of very different approach. I often use $broadcast and emit when build component based apps. Components don't communicate directly so it is necessary.