# Cannot transition to abstract state (angular-ui-router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

https://plnkr.co/edit/5JhQx64WF3tgdm02qKzJ?p=preview

[image]

All I did that broke my app was remove the ui-sref (I never like using that anyways) and went with a `$state.go` inside of the Javascript.

```
<tr ng-repeat="ticker in tickers">
  <!--<td>{{ ticker }} <button ui-sref="dash.tags({ticker: ticker})">Click Me</button></td>-->
  <td>{{ ticker }} <button ng-click="clickTicker(ticker)">Click Me</button></td>
</tr>
```

---

```
$scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
  $state.go('dash', { ticker: ticker });
}
```

---

If I don't have `abstract: true` in my parent `dashboard` state object then for some reason my TagsList component disappears.

Full code below:

```
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dash?AAA');

    var dash = {
      name: 'dash',
      url: '/dash',
      abstract: true,
      views: {
        '': { templateUrl: 'dashboard.html' },
        'tickersList@dash': {
          templateUrl: 'tickers-list.html',
          controller: 'tickersController'
        },
        'alertsList@dash': {
          controller: 'alertsController',
          templateUrl: 'alerts-list.html',
        }
      }
    };

    var tickers = {
      name: 'dash.tickers',
      url: '?ticker',
      params: {
        ticker: 'AAA'
      },
      views: {
        'tickersList@dash': {
          templateUrl: 'tickers-list.html',
          controller: 'tickersController'
        }
      }
    }

    var tags = {
      name: 'dash.tags',
      url: '?ticker',
      params: {
        ticker: 'AAA'
      },
      views: {
        'tagsList@dash': {
          templateUrl: 'tags-list.html',
          controller: 'tagsController'
        }
      }
    }

    $stateProvider
      .state(dash)
      .state(tags)

});

routerApp.controller('tagsController', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $scope.ticker = $state.params.ticker;

    function getList(ticker) {
      switch(ticker) {
          case 'AAA' : return ['aaa tag 1', 'aaa tag 2', 'aaa tag 3'];
          case 'BBB' : return ['bbb tag 1', 'bbb tag 2', 'bbb tag 3'];
          case 'CCC' : return ['ccc tag 1', 'ccc tag 2', 'ccc tag 3'];
      } 
    }

    $scope.tags = getList($state.params.ticker);

    this.$onInit = function() {
      console.log('onInit tagsController');
    };
});

routerApp.controller('tickersController', function($scope, $state) {
    $scope.tickers = [
      'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC'
    ];

    $scope.clickTicker = function(ticker) {
      $state.go('dash', { ticker: ticker });
    }

    this.$onInit = function() {
      console.log('onInit tickersController', $state.params.ticker);
    };
});

routerApp.controller('alertsController', function($scope, $state) {
    this.$onInit = function() {
      console.log('onInit alertsController', $state.params.ticker);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$state.go` you go to `/dash?ticker=ticker`, but `/dash` is an abstract state, so this is why you get an error.

Your `tickers` and `tags` states have their urls defined incorrectly. You probably want something like `url:  'tickers?ticker'`.