# How to navigate from a login state to an abstract dashboard state?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state-management

https://plnkr.co/edit/ByatrCzdUJfAV3oc8XPq?p=preview

^ On line 10, if you put back in the `abstract:true` key you will see the tags view appear in this plnkr app.

---

However my problem is that in my **real app** it won't let me use the `abstract` key because you first start at a `login` state and then transition to the `dashboard` state.

And the abstract key allows me to add the additional `tags` state as a child of `dashboard`.

When I have that key in there and I login in my real app this is the error I get:

> Error: Cannot transition to abstract state 'dashboard'

[image]

#### Plnkr code:

```
var dash = {
  name: 'dash',
  url: '/dash?ticker',
  // abstract: true,
  views: {
    '': { templateUrl: 'dashboard.html' },
    'tickersList@dash': {
      templateUrl: 'tickers-list.html',
      controller: 'tickersController'
    },
    'alertsList@dash': {
      templateUrl: 'alerts-list.html',
      controller: 'alertsController'
    }
  }
};

var tags = {
  name: 'dash.tags',
  url: '?ticker',
  params: {
    ticker: 'AAA'
  },
  views: {
    'tagsList@dash': {
      templateUrl: 'tags-list.html',
      controller: 'tagsController'
    }
  }
}

$stateProvider
  .state(dash)
  .state(tags);
```

---

## Real app

#### LoginController:

```
$state.go('dashboard')
```

#### STATE_CONSTANTS:

dashboard state object:

```
.constant('STATE_CONSTANTS', {
  dash: {
    name: 'dashboard',
    // abstract: true,
    url: `/dashboard?ticker?start_epoch?end_epoch?timespan?group?sort?term_id_1?term_id_2?term_id_3?social?stream?links?retweets?tags_open?feed_open?chart_alerts?chart_max`,
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: 'dash/dashboard_container.html',
            controller: function(UserFactory, container, user) {
                this.container = container;
                UserFactory.storeUser(user);
            },
            controllerAs: 'dc',
            bindToController: true,
            resolve: {
                user: (AuthFactory) => AuthFactory.check_login(),
                settings: (user, UserFactory) => UserFactory.settings(user),
                container: ($stateParams, TagsFactory) => TagsFactory.createTerms($stateParams)
            }
        },
        'platformHeader@dashboard': {
            templateUrl: 'headers/platform/platform_header.html',
            controller: 'PlatformCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'ph'
        },
        'timespanHeader@dashboard': {
            templateUrl: 'headers/timespan/timespan_header.html',
            controller: 'TimeHeaderCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'thc'
        },
        'tickersPanel@dashboard': {
            templateUrl: 'tickers/panel/tickers_panel.html',
            controller: 'TickersPanelCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'tikp'
        },
    },
    params: {
        ticker: '',
    },
    data: { authorizedRoles: ['All'] }
},
```

#### login state object:

```
login: {
    name: 'login',
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'auth/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
    data: { authorizedRoles: ['All'] }
}
```

#### dashboard.html template

```
<div>
    <header>
        <div ui-view="platformHeader"></div>
        <div ui-view="timespanHeader"></div>
    </header>

    <aside>
        <!-- the headers and tickersPanel are all child states of
             dashboard state -->
        <div ui-view="tickersPanel"></div>
        <!-- tags is a seperate state from dashboard -->
        <div ui-view="tagsPanel"></div>
    </aside>
//...
```

#### app.js

```
$stateProvider
    .state(STATE_CONSTANTS.login)
    .state(STATE_CONSTANTS.password)
    .state(STATE_CONSTANTS.passwordreset)
    .state(STATE_CONSTANTS.settings)
    .state(STATE_CONSTANTS.settingsDefault)
    .state(STATE_CONSTANTS.settingsAlerts)
    .state(STATE_CONSTANTS.dash)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is right. You cannot transit to abstract state. Look at your example from plunker.

```js
var dash = {
  name: 'dash',
  url: '/dash?ticker'

var tags = {
  name: 'dash.tags',
  url: '?ticker',
```

You have an abstract state "dash" and you have a child state "dash.tags" which is not abstract. So you can transit only to child state.

In your app, you try transiting to an abstract state which is not possible. 
Abstract states are used if you want to have some basic state with common behavior (parent state). You cannot transit to such states but they can have some basic template, resolve functions... So, you have to remove abstract flag or create a child state.

Comment: Ugh there is no way around this? The reason I separated out the tags state from the dashboard state is so that I can control which components refresh every time the state changes. Right now in my app all components refresh / onInit, however that is not the desired functionality. They should only refresh if they have too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254616/how-to-prevent-state-from-refreshing-any-component-that-does-not-rely-on-the-s

Comment: So why do you need "abstract: true" flag in your real app? You can just remove it. The reason of existing this flag is not to have ability transition to such states and you need this flag if you do have child states. In your app you don't have child states, only one state "dashboard". So don't murk it as abstract.

Comment: You wrote "And the abstract key allows me to add the additional tags state as a child of dashboard.".
But you can create child states of not abstract parent states as well!